# how to read ajax with json to servlet

Tags: java

I need your help to read a JSON from JQuery AJAX to my servlet.
I want to parse the internal data from the ajax call to jsonObject.

My code get facebook user information and pass the relavent data to json, then send AJAX call to servlet.
How do I read these parameter in my servlet request?

```
 var jsonUserInfo = [];
      jsonUserInfo.push({"id"           :   (response["id"]         ? response["id"]            : "wnull")}); 
      jsonUserInfo.push({"first_name"   :   (response["first_name"] ? response["first_name"]    : "wnull")});  
      jsonUserInfo.push({"last_name"    :   (response["last_name"]  ? response["last_name"]     : "wnull")});  
      jsonUserInfo.push({"username" :   (response["username"]   ? response["username"]      : "wnull")});  
      jsonUserInfo.push({"birthday"     :   (response["birthday"]   ? response["birthday"]      : "wnull")});  
      jsonUserInfo.push({"gender"       :   (response["gender"]     ? response["gender"]        : "wnull")});  
      jsonUserInfo.push({"relationship_status": (response["relationship_status"] ? response["relationship_status"] : "wnull")});  
      jsonUserInfo.push({"timezone" :   (response["timezone"]   ? response["timezone"]      : "wnull")});  
      jsonUserInfo.push({"locale"   :   (response["locale"]     ? response["locale"]        : "wnull")});  
      jsonUserInfo.push({"verified"     :   (response["verified"]   ? response["verified"]      : "wnull")});  
      jsonUserInfo.push({"updated_time":    (response["updated_time"] ? response["updated_time"]: "wnull")});  
      jsonUserInfo.push({"interested_in": (response["interested_in"] ? response["interested_in"] : [])});  
      jsonUserInfo.push({"meeting_for":     (response["meeting_for"] ? response["meeting_for"]  : [])});
```

And here is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({ url: "MainController",
     type:"POST",
     data: ({   "action"    : "setFacebookUserInfo",
                "userInfo"  : jsonUserInfo,
                "servlet"   : "UserProfile"
            }),
     dataType:"json",
     contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
     success: function(data){
        alert("here");
     },
     cache: true,
     ifModified: true
    });
```

How do I parse 'jsonUserInfo' object in my servlet with HttpServletRequest?
I'm using JSON-org jar.

Thanks,
Ido

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about JSON-org but with [JSON-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) you'd just do `JSONObject jsonobject = (JSONObject)(new JSONParser().parse(jsonstring));` or `JSONArray jsonarray = (JSONArray)(new JSONParser().parse(jsonstring));`

In org.json this seems to be done as follows: `JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(jsonstring));` or `JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(new JSONTokener(jsonstring));`

Comment: First, Thomas thanks for your answer. How do i get 'jsonstring' data, if i use: JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(request.getParameter("userInfo"))); i get an error.

Comment: I get an exception about null object: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.json.JSONTokener.more(JSONTokener.java:98)
 at org.json.JSONTokener.next(JSONTokener.java:108)
 at org.json.JSONTokener.nextClean(JSONTokener.java:162)
 at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:178)

Comment: Well, I'm no JavaScript expert but I'd guess the problem is either the `contentType` field in your call or you should name the parameter `userInfo` instead of `"userInfo"`.